# pandas: How to add an index-like column based upon column groupings?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to add col3 to an existing pandas dataframe (col1, col2) where col3 is like an index (starting from 1) of each group in col1.

```
        col1    col2    col3  
0       AAAA    fooW       1
1       AAAA    fooX       2
2       AAAA    fooY       3
3       AAAA    fooZ       4
4       BBBB    fooW       1
5       BBBB    fooX       2
6       CCCC    barV       1
7       CCCC    barW       2
8       CCCC    barX       3
9       CCCC    barY       4
10      CCCC    barZ       5
```

Comment: groupby + cumcount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first want to groupby 'col1' and then apply some function to get the index of the row within the group. `cumcount` is one that will do the job.

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()
```

Comment: Just what I wanted. Just needed to add df['col3'] = df.col3 + 1 to get the counts starting from 1.